# Solve BVP for an array of known parameters

Tags: python, scipy

I've built a model that relies on `scipy.integrate.solve_bvp` but am struggling to optimize the solution for curve fitting. The core issue is I'd like to provide several values of a known parameter at once and have `solve_bvp` return the full solution for each value of that parameter.

Here's an example boundary value problem taken from scipy's docs:

y'' + k * exp(y) = 0

y(0) = y(1) = 0

Rearranging into two first-order ODEs:

y1' = y2

y2' = -k * exp(y1)

```py
def model(x, k):
    def fun(x, y):
        return np.vstack((y[1], -k * np.exp(y[0])))

    def bc(ya, yb):
        return np.array([ya[0], yb[0]])

    y_0 = np.zeros((2, x.size))

    res = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y_0)

    return res.y[0]
```

My goal would be to pass `k = np.array([1, 2])` and `x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)` to `model()` and it return an array with shape `(2, 100)`. As written, the above code would fail when trying to broadcast `k * y[0]`.

I'm currently using the brute force approach below, but am wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this without resorting to for loops.

```py
def vector_func(x, k):
    Y = np.empty((len(k), len(x)))

    for i, k in enumerate(k):
        Y[i] = model(x, k)

    return Y

vector_func(x, k=np.array([1, 2]))
```

For context, in my actual scenario, `k` is a measured value and I'm using a model to predict `y`.
Since these are measured "parameters", using `solve_bvp`'s `p` argument doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, `solve_bvp` only solves a single problem at a time, so loops are your only option.